# Need to sort all of the files in a folder based on a certain criteria and return the last file name

Tags: vb.net, file, vba, sorting, directory

I have vb.net code that was given to me by a coworker that works in VB.net, but it doesn't work in VBA. I'm using that piece of code in a VBA file. Is there a way to change the syntax to work in VBA, or run it in VB.net from VBA or something. Or is there a completely different way to accomplish this all together?  I haven't had any luck trying to change the code or searching for an answer yet.

```
    Sub UpdateTVGData()

    Dim vPath As String = GetPath("PR.G.ZMDPPL.TVG")

End Sub

Function GetPath(ByVal vFIle As String) As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\sw100313\ZMD_Archives", vFIle + ".*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim sortcrit(files.Length - 1) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To files.Length - 1
        sortcrit(i) = Val(Mid(files(i), Len(files(i)) - 6, 4))
    Next i
    System.Array.Sort(sortcrit, files)
    Path = files(files.Length - 1)
    Path = Left(Path, 35)
    'clean up
    files = Nothing
    sortcrit = Nothing

    Return Path
End Function
```

Comment: Are the files all in the same folder and at the same level, or are there subfolders also containing files to be returned?  Which part are you having problems translating into VBA?  In VBA you can use `Dir()` to loop through all matching files in a folder (lots of examples here on SO), and while you're doing that you can examine each file name and save the one with Max/Min value of `Mid(fileName, Len(fileName)-6, 4)`

Comment: I'm trying your method but now it is giving me error 52 bad filename or number. I know it is the correct path.  Does it matter that it's on a network?  I'm connected to the network. Also it is a folder full of other folders, and I'm trying to pick the most recent folder and then a certain file in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the Dir() function to pick the correct folder based on the other posts I've seen here, but I'm getting "" for the value of foldnm on the first iteration.  If I use shell and the same file path, I can open the folder, so I don't think the path is the problem.

```
Sub get_file()

File_pth = "explorer.exe \\sw100313.w10\ZMD_Archives"
ctr = 1
max_folder_val = 0

foldnm = Dir(File_pth, vbDirectory)
Do While foldnm <> ""
Mid(fileName, Len(fileName)-6, 4)
ctr = ctr + 1
foldnm = Dir()
If Mid(foldnm, Len(foldnm)-6, 4) > max_folder_val Then
max_folder = foldnm
max_folder_val= Mid(foldnm, Len(foldnm)-6, 4)
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `explorer.exe` from the path.  You may also need to exclude the folders `.` and `..`.  A good place to start is to use Debug.Print to output the folder names to the Immediate window.